# Manipulating pdf and text in it

Tags: python, excel, data-manipulation, text-extraction, pdf-parsing

Currently I am working on a database to create a  Excel sheet for syllabus mapping.
I have to extract particular data from pdf files and then separate name books and their publishers in different columns.
I already has list of all Book Publishers.
I have to map it with books.
I can use python and Excel [Sample of Name of books and their publishers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH9FP.jpg)

I tried to copy particular texts from file then delimit.

Comment: I don't see any question or issue you may be having ...